# how to display .innerHtml message on below of the field in Visual force page

Tags: visualforce

```
function validationfun() { if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form:Email}').value=='') { document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form:Email}').style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form:Email}').innerHTML= "Field is required";
}
else {
savesf();
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="NewLead" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" id="page">
<apex:form styleClass="myFormStyle" id="form">

<apex:inputField value="{!le.Email}" id="Email"/>

<apex:actionFunction name="savesf" action="{!submitLead}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="validationfun(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: You could just use `required="true"` instead of writing JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Page will be like,

```
<apex:page controller="NewLead" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" id="page">
<apex:form styleClass="myFormStyle" id="form">

<apex:inputField value="{!le.Email}" id="Email"/>
<Label id="errorMsg"></Label>

<apex:actionFunction name="savesf" action="{!submitLead}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="validationfun(); return false;"/>
```

Your Javascript will be,

```
function validationfun() { 
   if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form:Email}').value=='') {
       document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = "inline"; 
       document.getElementById('errorMsg').innertHTML('Value required...');
   }
   else {
      document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = "none";
      savesf();
   }
}
```